# Ruby Sinatra app for downloading a file (as streaming)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a sinatra app, where I want to make a download feature. This download take data from table and make excel to download for user.

```
require 'csv'
get '/download' do 
     data = [{:name => "john", :age => 12, :state => 'ca'}, {:name => "tony", :age => 22, :state => 'va'}]

     # I want to download this data as excel file and the content of file should be as follows:
     # name,age,state
     # john,12,ca
     # tony,22,va
     # I don't want to save data as a temp file on the server and then throw to user for download 
     # rather I want to stream data for download on the browser. So I used this, 
     # but it is not working

     send_data (data, :type => 'application/csv', :disposition => 'attachment')
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Or how to achieve, what I am trying to do? I was trying to follow http://sinatra.rubyforge.org/api/classes/Sinatra/Streaming.html

UPDATE:
I am not married to send_data method of sinatra. If streaming blocks my server for that duration, then I am open to alternatives.

Comment: Note that streaming blocks your server for that duration. A Tempfile doesn't have this restriction, as nginx or whatever you use should handle that.

Comment: @Tass Ok. So you suggest, I should make a temp file and send user to download it? If so, then I would need to remove that temp file as well. Or other way send_file of apache/nginx can handle it. But please assume, I don't want to use send_file of apache/nginx . so what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
get '/download' do 
    data = [{:name => "john", :age => 12, :state => 'ca'}, {:name => "tony", :age => 22, :state => 'va'}]

    content_type 'application/csv'
    attachment "myfilename.csv"
    data.each{|k, v|
       p v
    }
end
```

This works for me. I know it is incomplete as I have to put header and comma in the excel file with line break. But this works.